# JasperException on compiling with OpenJDK 11

Tags: java, tomcat, java-11

Using Tomcat 8.5.38, unable to compile with OpenJDK 11 and getting below exception. Tried using tomcat jasper 9.0.16 as well and still the same exception.
Verified that the specified directory in uriroot is a pre-existing directory.

```
<jasper2 outputDir="${buildDir}/testAppTemp"
    uriroot="${buildDir.testApp}"
    validateXml="false"
    webXmlFragment="${buildDir}/testAppTemp/generated_web.xml"/>
```

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The -uriroot option must specify a pre-existing directory.

PS: Compiles successfully with JDK 8.

Comment: Does this help? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206310099-Error-while-compiling-after-upgrade

Comment: [Please check this link](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1107241/java-11-support)

Comment: @SagarShetty this question is about [Jasper](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jasper-howto.html), not [Jasper](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library)